# Вырезание текста

Tags: python

я новичок в python. У меня возникла проблема с вырезанием текста, я получаю текст в формате json

```
{"id":1,"login":"Test","balance":999,"winnings":0,"token":"SimpleToken","ban":0,"ban_why":null}
```

Мне необходимо создать переменную в которой будет находится только лишь токен. Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Почитать про json/словари.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете привести ваш JSON к словарю методом `loads`, а потом достать токен из словаря по ключу:

```
import json

# в этой переменной JSON указывается, разумеется, не напрямую, я оттуда, откуда вы его берёте у себя в программе
j = '{"id":1,"login":"Test","balance":999,"winnings":0,"token":"SimpleToken","ban":0,"ban_why":null}' 

token = json.loads(j)['token']
print(token)
```

Результат:

```
SimpleToken
```